# I have an Error: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, dotenv

I am facing this issue of MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined" in my Index.js. Here is my Index.js file

```
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cors from "cors";
//routes
import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.js";
//call dotenv
dotenv.config();
//initialize this app
const app = express();

//set up body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));

//must be above the routes
app.use(cors());

//use middleware for the prefix routes the posts routes will be reached by localhost:3001/posts/ ....
app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

//host data base through the cloud
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

mongoose
  .connect(
    process.env.MONGODB_URI
  )
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server is running on port: ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

The `processs.env.MONGODB_URI` is in the .env file. the .env file is like so:

```
PORT=3001
MONGODB_URI=<mongodb-atlas-string>
```

yet The process.env.MONGODB_URI is undefined when I run it with the frontend (using concurrently); however, it works fine in just the backend.

Comment: If I test your code as-is (with route setup removed) it works fine for me. Try adding `console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI);` after `dotenv.config()`

Comment: Please make sure that your MONGODB_URI is some what similar to this:

"mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@<server.url>/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
Also let me know what Node & Mongodb version are you using in your application.
I would recommend to use the latest LTS version.

Comment: I am using the Latest Node LTS version. Now, if i test the server side only, I am connected succesfully and `console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI)` is indeed the mongodb uri; however, when I run the whole application (frontend & backend with concurrently), the mongodb_URI decides to become undefined.

Comment: @AbdullahZaydi has this happened to you?

Comment: I guess then the problem is not with the node app but with ```concurrently```. I need more details about your code setup and how you run both frontend and backend.
Also do check our ```pm2```. I guess it's a lot more better than concurrently.

Comment: Can you post your concurrently command? My guess is that it changes the working directory so your backend doesn't use the correct .env file. Try adding a path: `dotenv.config({ path: '/custom/path/to/.env' })`

Comment: concurrently command `    "start": "concurrently \"node server/index.js\" \"cd client && npm start\"",`